# Rmpi send/receive hanging?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, mpi, mcmc

I am writing the code for a population MCMC. I will try to provide as much information I think could help, so please bear with me.

I am using tempered distributions and I want to perform exchange moves, i.e a moves that propose to swap the value of two chains.

### What I have done (exchange happening in the master)

I had written this initially by

- letting each chain mutate for a specified number of iterations n.
- at every n-th iteration, I would send the slaves' results to the master and there attempt an exchange of parameters between chains.
- Then send updated values back to slaves and repeat the process.

### What I want to achieve (exchange directly between slaves)

This is working fine, but I wanted to clean up my code and remove unnecessary communication between master and slave . That is, let the slaves communicate directly between them.

So  assuming I am spawning 10 slaves,

- at iteration n, I want  to let slave1-slave2, slave3-slave4, ...., slave9-slave10 communicate between them
- at iteration 2*n, I want to let slave2-slave3, slave4-slave5, ...slave8-slave9 communicate between them

and so on, so that I let samples travel through the temperature ladder.

### The problem

And this is where I am facing a problem.
I think I am managing to send a value from one slave to another (my print statement "Succesfully sent" gets printed in the log files of the slaves that are sending) but this doesn't seem to be received (my "Succesfully received" statement doesn't get printed in the log of the partner slaves).

And the program just hangs. I think maybe I have caused a deadlock, but I am not sure what I have done wrong?

Could you please advise? I have used as guide this Parallel Tempering  R code
http://www.lindonslog.com/mathematics/parallel-tempering-r-rmpi/

Please see below my code

Many thanks!

Sofia

```
ind <- mpi.comm.rank()
oddFlag<-0   ### object to flag code suitable for odd/even numbered slaves.

for  (i in  1:TotalIter)  {
##### normal MCMC move (single chain mutation) -  logL.current

 if ( i%%exchangeInterval == 0 ){   ### every nth (right now 5th) iteration, attempt an exchange  

message("\n\nAttempt an exchange move")
oddFlag<-oddFlag+1     
exchange<-0
logL.partner<-0

  if (ind%%2 == oddFlag%%2) {  ###when oddFlag even , the following code concerns even-numbered slaves. When odd number, it concerns odd-numbered slaves.                                                  
  ind.partner<-ind+1

  if (0<ind.partner && ind.partner<(noChains+1)){
    message("This is the slave: ", ind, " and its partner is: ", ind.partner)
    message("The tag for receiving logL.partner is: ", ind.partner)          
    logL.partner<-mpi.recv.Robj(source=ind.partner,tag=ind.partner)  #### receive the logL of partner                    
    message("Succesfully received")
    message("This is the logL.partner: ", logL.partner)
    exchanges.attempted<-exchanges.attempted+1

    if (runif(1)< min(1, exp((logL.partner - estimatorSelf)*(temper[ind] - temper[ind.partner] )))) {    ############# exp((chain2 - chain1)*(T1 - T2))                                          
      message("I exchanged the values")
      exchange<-1
      print(exchange)
      exchanges.accepted<-exchanges.accepted+1
    }
    mpi.send.Robj(obj=exchange,dest=ind.partner,tag=15*ind)
  }

  if (exchange==1){
### exchange parameters  with mpi.send.Robj/mpi.recv.Robj functions
  }

} else {  ##### ###when oddFlag even , the following code concerns odd-numbered slaves. For oddFlag odd, it concerns even-numbered slaves.                              
  ind.partner<-ind-1

  if (0<ind.partner && ind.partner<(noChains+1)){
    message("This is the slave: ", ind, " and its partner is: ", ind.partner)
    message("The tag for sending logL.current is: ", ind)
    mpi.send.Robj(obj=logL.current,dest=ind.partner,tag=ind)  ### send logL to partner
    message("Succesfully sent")

    exchange<-mpi.recv.Robj(source=ind.partner, tag=15*ind.partner)
    message("I received the exchange message")
  }

  if (exchange==1){
 ### exchange parameters send/receive functions
   }
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Do all of the receiving slaves contain the message "The tag for receiving logL.partner is:" in their log file and none of them say "Succesfully received"?  Is `noChains` set to the number of slaves that you spawned?  And is this code in a function that you executed via `mpi.remote.exec`?

Comment: Thank you Steve. Yes the message "the tag for receiving.." is printed in all the receiving slaves' logs while none of them have the "Succesfully received". Sorry I didn't clarify the other 2 points in my initial post but noChains is indeed the number of slaves I have spawned. And yes this bit of code is included in a bigger function I execute with mpi.remote.exec

Comment: Are you executing the R script using mpirun?  Does it make any difference if you do?

Comment: No, I was not aware of mpirun. Let me check it out and will report back. thanks!

Comment: Just make sure that you use the '-n 1' option when executing a script that spawns workers.  I suggest it because the use of mpirun sometimes works better, even when running on a single machine.  It's necessary in order to execute on multiple machines.

Comment: @Lindon as well: ahh it works fine with mpirun!! I am so happy :-) Not sure I understand mpirun's wizardry and what problem exactly it solved. But nevertheless that solved it. Many thanks Steve! (and Lindon for taking the time and of course providing your code online). Can't upvote the comments or answers of you good people unfortunately, as I just signed up and don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 0):

This seems very strange. To my knowledge the send and receive commands are locking so for the send to work without the receive to work strikes me as a bit odd. Have you tried the code on the guide? If you like I can send you the entire R-code just to see if it works on your system. If the code on the guide works then you can safely say that it isn't a problem with your MPI setup.

One thing you might try is for the receive command instead of using ind.partner you could use mpi.any.source() (i think is the correct one) which will accept a message of any tag. If this resolves your deadlock, it could be a problem with the tags (but by eye there doesn't seem anything wrong to me).

Another thing you might try is removing the "source=" and the "tag=" on the receive commands. I notice in my code that I don't have any there whilst I do for the send commands. Perhaps that was causing me too problems, but I can't quite remember. Let me know how it goes, I hope it all works out.

Comment: Hello Lindon, thanks for your reply! mpi.any.source() & mpi.any.tag() don't change anything.Removing the argument names and leaving just the values for the receive, also doesn't change sth. Sorry I didn't mentioned it initially, but yes I had tried the code in your guide and it seemed to be working fine. However when earlier today I incorporated your working code as it is in my code, (with the only modification of commenting out all the theta related lines) I observed the same issue:I could send but not receive... Now I am even more confused (but at least I can rule out problematic MPI setup).